# Joining 2 columns based on values in another using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of values in a column in a DataFrame which I want to use to filter another larger DataFrame that has 2 columns to match based upon.

Here is an example.

```python
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
     [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d"), (5, "e")],
     ("ID", "label1"))

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 2, "x"),
        (2, 1, "y"),
        (3, 1, "z"),
        (4, 6, "s"),
        (7, 2, "t"),
        (8, 9, "z")
    ],
    ("ID1", "ID2", "label2")
)
```

What I would like to get in the end is a DataFrame that has entries from `df2` where both `ID1` and `ID2` are in `df1`. In this case of the example, this would look like this;

```python
+---+---+------+
|ID1|ID2| label|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  2|     x|
|  2|  1|     y|
|  3|  1|     z|
+---+---+------+
```

I have tried doing this via a join like follows;

```python
df = df1.join(df2, (df1.ID == df2.ID1) | (df1.ID == df2.ID2))
```

but this explodes my table and gives me

```python
+---+------+---+---+------+
| ID|label1|ID1|ID2|label2|
+---+------+---+---+------+
|  1|     a|  1|  2|     x|
|  1|     a|  2|  1|     y|
|  1|     a|  3|  1|     z|
|  2|     b|  1|  2|     x|
|  2|     b|  2|  1|     y|
|  2|     b|  7|  2|     t|
|  3|     c|  3|  1|     z|
|  4|     d|  4|  6|     s|
+---+------+---+---+------+
```

Then,

```python
df = df1.join(df2, (df1.ID == df2.ID1) & (df1.ID == df2.ID2))
```

Obviously isn't what I want either........ any help folks?

Comment: The creation of `df1` gives error, because you can't create a tuple with one element using that syntax. You should put instead `[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)],("ID",)` (please note the inner commas!)

Comment: Thanks! I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach using spark-sql:

First register your DataFrames as tables:

```python
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
```

Next run the following query:

```python
df = sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT * FROM df2 WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT ID FROM df1) AND ID2 IN (SELECT ID FROM df1)"
)
df.show()
#+---+---+------+
#|ID1|ID2|label2|
#+---+---+------+
#|  3|  1|     z|
#|  2|  1|     y|
#|  1|  2|     x|
#+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use your initial join statement and further group the DataFrame and select the rows that occur twice, since `ID1` AND `ID2` should be present in `df1`. Thus they should occur twice in the result because the join should duplicate the row of `df2` with the two values of ID in `df1`.

The resulting statement looks like:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df2.join(
    df1,
    [(df1.ID==df2.ID1)|(df1.ID==df2.ID2)],
    how="left"
).groupBy("ID1","ID2","label").count().filter(col("count")==2).show()
```

The result is:

```python
+---+---+-----+-----+
|ID1|ID2|label|count| 
+---+---+-----+-----+ 
| 2 | 1 | y   | 2   | 
| 3 | 1 | z   | 2   | 
| 1 | 2 | x   | 2   |
+---+---+-----+-----+
```

If you dont like the count column you can append a `select("ID1","ID2","label")` to the statement

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! The only thing is I got an error stating 'NameError: name 'col' is not defined'

Comment: This is a function from `pyspark.sql.functions` but thanks to @pault he already edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersect after filter data separately. Here is the solution with using core spark api

```
>>> df1.show()
+---+------+
| ID|label1|
+---+------+
|  1|     a|
|  2|     b|
|  3|     c|
|  4|     d|
|  5|     e|
+---+------+

>>> df2.show()
+---+---+------+
|ID1|ID2|label2|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  2|     x|
|  2|  1|     y|
|  3|  1|     z|
|  4|  6|     s|
|  7|  2|     t|
|  8|  9|     z|
+---+---+------+

>>> df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1.ID == df2.ID1)).select(df2['*'])
>>> df4 = df1.join(df2, (df1.ID == df2.ID2)).select(df2['*'])
>>> df3.intersect(df4).show()
+---+---+------+                                                                
|ID1|ID2|label2|
+---+---+------+
|  2|  1|     y|
|  3|  1|     z|
|  1|  2|     x|
+---+---+------+
```